# get_meta_tags works for URLs, but not local files

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a script that will read the meta tags from all other files in a directory and display information on each. When I try to do this referring to the local file name, it doesn't work. But for some reason, when I reference the complete URL, it works, but is too slow to be useful.

When I turn on error reporting, I get this error each time through the loop:

> Undefined index: description in /path/to/my/script/index.php on line 83

Anybody know why remote files would work and local ones would not?

Here's the code that fails:

```
$dir   = '.';
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach ($files as &$value) {
   $tags = get_meta_tags($value);
   echo $tags['description'] . "<br>";
   }
```

But for some reason, this code works:

```
$dir   = '.';
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach ($files as &$value) {
   $tags = get_meta_tags('http://mydomain.com/path/' . $value);
   echo $tags['description'] . "<br>";
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure the file has a `description` tag? What does `var_dump($tags)` show?

Comment: I checked and the desciption tags are there, and I see them when I call the full URL of the local file. var_dump($tags) just shows this over and over: array(0) {}

Comment: Can you check what is in `var_dump($value)`?

Comment: var_dump($value) shows something like this for every loop: 
string(7) "009.php"